# Чтение файла excel и запись в базу данных asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Есть задача: пользователь выбирает файл excel с какими-то данными на своем компьютере, нажимает кнопку, программа(веб) читает excel файл и валидные данные вносит в базу данных.
Подскажите хорошее руководство по реализации данной идеи.

Answer (score 0):

Разбейте задачу на мелкие.

1. Отправка файла на сервер. Web MVC проект
2. Обработка Excel файла.
3. Работа с базами данных.

На каждый из них полно руководств.
[asp.net mvc](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/)
[Excel](https://razilov-code.ru/2017/12/13/microsoft-office-interop-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ставишь на странице форму для загрузки файла

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Your_Action", "Your_C", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="upload_t" />
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл"/>
}
```

2. Принимаешь на контроллере и обрабатываешь

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload_t)
    {
        //TODO
    }
```

Для парсинга Excel-файла могу порекомендовать библиотеку ClosedXML.